# Помогите разобраться в работе рекурсивного алгоритма на С++

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Объясните, как здесь работает рекурсия,ибо я не особо понимаю:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

int maxs(double*, int);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    randomize();
    double n;
    int i;
    cin >> n;
    double* a = new double[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        *(a + i) = random(21) - 10;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << *(a + i) << " ";

    cout << endl;
    double r = maxs(a, n - 1);
    cout << "Max value is " << r;
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int maxs(double* a, int n)
{
    double r1, r2;

    if (n == 0)
        return a[0];

    r1 = maxs(a, n / 2);
    r2 = maxs(a + n / 2 + 1, n - 1);
    return max(r1, r2);
}
```

Comment: Почему бы вам не спросить у того, кто вам этот некорректный код предоставил?:)

Comment: как бы это сказать, ах да-он работает

Comment: Начните с чтения этого http://th-algoritmov.narod.ru/8.htm - Ваш код максимально близкий к фибоначчи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас код всей программы не корректный.

Во-первых, размер массива должен иметь целый тип. Иначе количество выделенных элементов для массива и циклы, используемые для заполнения его, могут не соответствовать друг другу.

Например, допустим, что значение переменной `n` равно `1.5`. Тогда выделится массив, состоящий из 1 элемента, так как дробная часть числа будет отброшена.
Однако в этом цикле

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
*(a+i)=random(21)-10;
```

будут иметь две итерации для значений переменной `i` равных 0 и 1, так как оба эти значения меньше 1.5. В результате будет обращение к элементу массива с индексом 1, которого не существует. Поэтому программа имеет неопределенное поведение.

Функция также не корректная.

В теле функции возвращается объект типа `double` , который будет преобразован к типу `int`, так как это тип возвращаемого значения функции. Поэтому функция вернет не верное значение, если возвращаемый объект имеет дробную часть.

```
int maxs(double *, int  );
^^^
```

При вызове функции, не понятно почему, уменьшается размер массива

```
maxs(a,n-1);
       ^^^^
```

Поэтому внутри функции будет неправильно считаться число элементов.

В данных предложениях

```
r1=maxs(a,n/2);
r2=maxs(a+n/2+1,n-1);
```

по идеи ищутся максимальные элементы двух половинок массива. Однако количество элементов массива во второй половинке считается не верно

```
r2=maxs(a+n/2+1,n-1);
                ^^^^
```

Данная функция также имеет неопределенное поведение.

Вы сами можете легко в этом убедиться, запустив на выполнение такой простой пример

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int maxs (double *a,int n){
double r1,r2;
if(n==0)
  return a[0];
 r1=maxs(a,n/2);
 r2=maxs(a+n/2+1,n-1);
 return std:: max(r1,r2);
}

int main() 
{
    double a[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 100.123 };

    std::cout << maxs( a, 2 ) << std::endl;
}
```

В данной программе функция запускается для подмассива, состоящего из эдементов
1.1, 2.2, 3.3, так как второй параметр равен 2. Однако функция возвращает число 100 (даже не 100.123) вместо правильного значения 3.3.

Правильно будет написать функцию таким образом, чтобы она возвращала индекс максимального элемента. Тогда для пустого массива функция вернет индекс равный длине массива, то есть 0, и тем самым позволяет отличить, передан ли в функцию реальный массив, или пустой массив.

Вот как функция может выглядеть

```
size_t max_element( const double *a, size_t n )
{
    if ( n < 2 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        size_t i = max_element( a, n / 2 );
        size_t j = n / 2 + max_element( a + n / 2 , n - n / 2 );

        return a[i] < a[j] ? j : i;
    }
}
```

Сначала она проверяет, сколько элементов в массиве, то есть меньше 2 или нет. Если элементов в массиве меньше двух, то есть либо массив состоит из одного элемента либо пустой, то возвращается индекс этого элемента.

Иначе массив делится на две половинки: элементы с индексами меньше `n / 2` и элементы с индексами, начиная с `n /2` и до `n`. И Функция рекурсивно вызывается для каждой из половинок исходного массива. Затем на основе возвращенных из вызовов функции индексов максимальных элементов для каждой половинки массива сравниваются эти два максимальных элемента и индекс наибольшего из них в свою очередь возвращается из функции.

Вот демонстрационная программа, в которой вызывается ваша исходная функция и функция, предложенная мною, для подмассива из трех элементов

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

size_t max_element( const double *a, size_t n )
{
    if ( n < 2 )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        size_t i = max_element( a, n / 2 );
        size_t j = n / 2 + max_element( a + n / 2 , n - n / 2 );

        return a[i] < a[j] ? j : i;
    }
}

int maxs (double *a,int n){
double r1,r2;
if(n==0)
  return a[0];
 r1=maxs(a,n/2);
 r2=maxs(a+n/2+1,n-1);
 return std:: max(r1,r2);
}

int main() 
{
    double a[] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 100.123 };

    std::cout << maxs( a, 2 ) << std::endl;

    std::cout << a[max_element( a, 3 )] << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
100
3.3
```

Как видно из вывода ваша функция возвращает значение, которое даже не входит в подмассив { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 }, в то время, как вторая функция возвращает корректное значение `3.3`.

Работа функции простая. Допустим, имеется массив из четырех элементов { a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3] }. Вызывается функция с адресом первого элмента массива и числом элементов.

```
max_element( a, 4 )
```

В своем теле функция вызывает саму себя для подмассивов { a[0], a[1] } и { a[2], a[3] } следующим образом

```
max_element( a, 2 ) <== max_element( a, n / 2 )
```

и

```
max_element( a + 2, 2 ) <== max_element( a + т . 2, т - n / 2 )
```

То есть максимальный элемент всего массива массива ищется как наибольшее значение двух половинок массива.

```
a[0] a[1] a[2] a[3]
 |    |    |    |      
 ------    ------
 max1       max2
  |          |
  ------------ 
      max
```

Каждый рекурсивный вызов функции возвращает индекс максимального элемента в подмассиве путем деления исходного массива на две половинки. В функции эти индексы обозначены переменными `i` и `j`

Итак, после рекурсивного вызова получаем два индекса максимальных элементов соответственно для первой половинки массива и для второй половинки массива

```
size_t i = max_element( a, n / 2 );
size_t j = n / 2 + max_element( a + n / 2 , n - n / 2 );
```

Затем сравниваем эти максимальные элементы каждой из половинок, соответствующих полученным индексам и в конечном итоге возвращаем из функции индекс того  элемента из этих двух, который является максимальным

```
return a[i] < a[j] ? j : i;
```

Comment: Опытный QA конечно введет 1.5 и -10 (кстати, почему то этот вариант не был рассмотрен). Но Автор вопроса понимает, что там кол-во элементов и вводит именно кол-во элементов (то есть, целое число). Поэтому, приведение допустимо. И даже условия будут нормально выполнятся. Но ТС спрашивал то не об этом.

Comment: @KoVadim Автор вопроса, очевидно, не понимает, что он делает, а потому для количества элементов массива вводит переменную с плавающей запятой.

Comment: Кстати, в одном из примеров - две ошибки. Код даже не компилируется. Автор вопроса спрашивает не о ошибках, о том, как работает рекурсия.

Comment: Я не отрицаю , что мой код не идеален и даже забагован. Да и дело тут совсем не в этом то было. @VladfromMoscow я прошу вас, если конечно это вас сильно не затруднит "разжевать как младенцу",объяснить пошагово как работает ваша(именно ваша) рекурсивная функция.Премного благодарен.Я не понимаю как из того, что мы делим постоянно массив пополам мы и извлекаем максимальный элемент.

Comment: @KoVadim Автор спрашивает о конкретной функции, которая неверная и имеет неопределенное поведение. Поэтому рассказывать, как она "работает". когда она не работает, бессмысленно.